# About DWF AND PDF support in Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-viewer

I am following this blog "[DWF AND PDF SUPPORT IN FORGE VIEWER](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/dwf-and-pdf-support-forge-viewer)".

The example for DWF file does not work (the example for PDF file works).
It keeps loading without any error message.
Is there anyone who makes it work? How? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: the file needs to be local and accessible, can you please share that code snippet?